# My Java code wont spawn the next wave?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

So I am making a game where there are waves of enemies.  The Wave class contains an update method that updates all the enemies in an arraylist of enemies contained in the Wave class.  The Wave class also has a boolean called beat that decides whether or not the player has beaten the current wave.  I am now have been trying however to start the next wave after the player beats the first.  All waves in the arraylist start out with their beat variable as true except for the first.  There are currently only two waves.  I do not know why this is not working.  Thank You for any help.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1;i++)
    {
        if(!w.get(i).beat)
            w.get(i).update(g2d);
        else if(w.get(i).beat)
        {
            if(i-1 != -1)
            {
                if(w.get(i-1).beat && w.get(i).beat)
                {
                    w.get(i).beat = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will increment `i` to the next wave after setting the current wave's `beat` setting to `false`, and miss calling the `update` method for that case. It looks like you should either call its `update` method immediately after setting `beat = false`, or perform the `if` test in the opposite order like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numWaves;i++) // upper range should be the number of waves
{
    if(w.get(i).beat)
    {
        if(i>0)   // this can be simplified to "if (i>0)"
        {
            if(w.get(i-1).beat)  // no need to check w.get(i).beat here
            {
                w.get(i).beat = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        w.get(i).update(g2d);
}
```

I don't know why you'd initialize a wave's `beat` state to `true` then set it to `false` when its turn comes. Why not just initialize all to `false` since they really haven't been beat yet?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Turns out the actual problem was the way I was handling beat in the wave class' update method.  And I did use your suggestion of initializing beat as false and just having a field for if the wave is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your code but I can tell you 2 things. First of all, your loop never loops because as soon as the index is 1, it ends without executing the code a second time. Secondly

```
 if(i-1 != -1)
            {
                if(w.get(i-1).beat && w.get(i).beat)
                {
                    w.get(i).beat = false;
                }
            }
```

is always false due to what I said.